# How to detect Keyboard "PAGE UP" key pressed in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I want to detect whenever the user presses "**page up**" or "**page down**" key.

I used `UITextView` and **[UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput: modifierFlags: action:]**,

and it worked on iOS 7.

```
[UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:[NSString hexToString:@"0b"] modifierFlags:0 action: @selector(pageUpKeyPressed:)]
```

*(PageUp: 0b, PageDown: 0c)*

But it doesn't work on iOS8.

Is there anyway to detect "*page up/down*" key pressed on iOS 8?

Comment: Where is page up/down coming from? Is this an external keyboard? AFAIK, there's no iOS software key for page up or page down. You can detect arrow keys UIKeyInputUpArrow and modifiers UIKeyModifierControl. But those don't get you short keyboard equivalent of fn up arrow, which is something used as a replacement for extended keyboard page up button. Let me know if you want help with arrows and modifiers.

Comment: I already answered this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32274319/swift-2-ios-bluetooth-keyboard-key-press-detection/36377423#36377423

Answer (score 2):

I noticed that the predefined constants UIKeyInputUpArrow etc were just strings containing the name of the symbol like @"UIKeyInputUpArrow".  So I tried using

```
[UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"UIKeyInputPageUp" 
                    modifierFlags:0 
                           action:@selector(pageUpKeyPressed:)];
```

just on a whim.  Lo and behold, it works! (in iOS 10)
Don't know if this qualifies as using an undocumented API or not.  Using it may or may not get your app rejected from the App Store.