# iOS Swift Bluetooth Keyboard keypress detection

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

In Swift 2 on iOS 8.4 how do I detect when a Bluetooth keyboard's `Up`, `Down`, or `Space` bar keys are pressed so I can respond with an action? 
Example code would be helpful.

Answer (score 10):

Sorry I'm so late, I just realized I can help you.

What you need to use is UIKeyCommand. Check this out: http://nshipster.com/uikeycommand/

Note that to detect arrow key presses you'll need `input: UIKeyInputLeftArrow` instead of `input: "j"` (or equiv.) when that shows up. You'll also want to have no modifiers (so the user won't have to press CMD-left arrow): please refer to [Key Commands with no modifier flags—Swift 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35671226/key-commands-with-no-modifier-flags-swift-2).

Basically, you'll want something along the lines of this after (outside) your viewdidload:

```
override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
    return true
}

    override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
    return [
        UIKeyCommand(input: UIKeyInputDownArrow, modifierFlags: [], action: "DownArrowPress:"),
        UIKeyCommand(input: UIKeyInputUpArrow, modifierFlags: [], action: "UpArrowPress:"),
        UIKeyCommand(input: " ", modifierFlags: [], action: "SpaceKeyPress:")]
    }

// ...

func DownArrowPress(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
 // this happens when you press the down arrow.   
}
func UpArrowPress(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
 // this happens when you press the up arrow.   
}
func SpaceKeyPress(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
 // this happens when you press the space key.   
}
```

I hope this helps, comment back @owlswipe if you need more help or something isn't right.

Comment: I tried applying `UIKeyCommand` with the `input: " "` but the action doesn't get called when the space key is pressed. It works for other keys like the return key : `input: "\r"`

(Swift 5)

Comment: @DanielFarrell do you have the full access keyboard active?

Answer (score 0):

owlswipe's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36377423/740997) worked for me, however, I had to make the following changes for Swift 5:

```swift
  @objc func DownArrowPress(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
    print("DOWNARROWPRESS")
  }
  @objc func UpArrowPress(sender: UIKeyCommand) {
    print("UPARROWPRESS")
  }

  override var keyCommands: [UIKeyCommand]? {
  return [
    UIKeyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputDownArrow, modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(DownArrowPress)),
    UIKeyCommand(input: UIKeyCommand.inputUpArrow, modifierFlags: [], action: #selector(UpArrowPress))
    ]
  }
```