# Key Commands with no modifier flags—Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, bluetooth

I built a calculator in swift, and I would like an iPad user who has a bluetooth keyboard be able to type without any onscreen keyboard distractions. I think the best way to do this is with `UIKeyCommand`s, but I am running into a problem: whereas with objective-c you can do something like this `[UIKeyCommand keyCommandWithInput:@"f" modifierFlags:0 action:@selector(keyPressF)]`, in swift there can not be '0' modifier flags.

Please answer one of these!

**How can I make things happen in swift when the user types a certain character on an iPad Bluetooth Keyboard without a text field as the first responder, and without pressing the control or option key?**

**Something happens when I press command-j. Can I make something happen when I press the 4 key on my iPad BT keyboard?"**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can help you with both of these.

1. In Swift 2.0 and above you have to pass an empty array instead of 0. To make your initializer work it would look like: `UIKeyCommand(input: "f", modifierFlags: [], action: "keyPressF")`. The reason why is because 0 isn't defined anywhere in the UIKeyModifierFlags struct. This is pretty common practice in UIKit so it's a good idea to get used to using this pattern for empty options.
2. Yes! Just pass `input: "4"` in your initializer instead of `input: "j"`.